# Match Function VBA didn't work for Date, with array is defined in Name Manager

Tags: excel

I also need to apply Match function in VBA, and the Arg 1 also has to be Date. The Array (Arg 2) I defined in the "Name Manager" (Tab Formula of Excel). I need to use the Name Manager since I have several array/ table reference based on the type of currency. For example, if the currency is USD, the reference table is USDREF which I defined as Range("B21:B36"). For the other currency, ex. JPY, I use array/ table reference JPYREF which is defined as JPYREF from Range("B36:B50"). It applies for other currencies. Here's my code :

```vb
Dim Original As Workbook
Dim SRate As Worksheet
Dim ccy As String
Dim i, j, k, l, Rank1, Rank2, Rate1, Rate2 As Integer
Dim srow, erow, x As Long
Dim DateFCYIDR, Date1, Date2 As Date
Sub fcyidr()

Set Original = ThisWorkbook
Set SRate = Original.Sheets("Rate")

SRate.Activate
Range("A36").Select

ccy = ActiveCell.Value

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    For i = 1 To 15
    
        If i = 1 Or i = 15 Then
            j = ActiveCell.Row
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = "=+$G$" & j - 15 & "/G" & j
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            
        Else
        
            DateFCYIDR = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            
            Rank1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(DateFCYIDR), USDREF, 0)

        
        End If
        
    Next i

Wend
```

where USDREF is defined in Name Manager. But it didn't work.
How do I solved the problem?

Comment: You should show us how you defined USDREF in the code. Is a range object? Otherwise you have to refer to the range like this: `thisworkbook.names("USDREF").refersToRange`.

Comment: Have you tested the vlookup() directly on the sheet? If it works there then next try vbba...